# How to handle many connections in java using Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have one confusion about a design problem: so usually in the server loop if we accept a new client, we spawn a new thread to handle the connection. However, suppose there are like 100 clients connected to the server, obviously we cannot spawn 100 threads to do all of the story. How do you usually deal with this case in Java? I don't want to limit the number of connections to be a small number. Can event-driven socket programming solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> obviously we cannot spawn 100 threads

Certainly you can spawn 100 threads. You can spawn thousands. Tens of thousands. Maybe more. A hundred is nothing.

Comment: Well so just let the kernel to schedule the order and no need to worry anything?

Comment: Exactly. Don't worry about it.